# I'm trying to open the admin website for my project but it isn't coming up, rather it shows the Django install worked successfully page. What can I do

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've created superuser and I've also ran the server yet it keeps showing the django "install worked successfully" page. Please what can I do?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to go to `http://127.0.0.1/8000/admin/`.

For templates, set default route in project's urls.py as:

```py
urlpatterns=[
   path('',include("any_app_name.urls"))
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For standard installation the admin site path is `/admin` so append that after your URL where you see "install worked successfully" page.

Comment: I did that but somehow, it isn't taking me to the admin site. It keeps showing the install page

Comment: @Jessica Share your project's urls.py, or try to restart the sever again maybe in another port as `python manage.py runserver 5000` then append `/admin/`